# Mysql Subquery with join

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have quite a complicated query (for me) that I'm not sure how to execute, although I have tried. I have a

`user table`

`license table` FK user.id is found in license.parent_id and license.child_id

`item table` FK is user.id is found in item.user_id

I need to count the number of items for each user in the `item table` that belong to a user and their licensees where the license hasn't expired.

This is as far as I've got with it so far.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT id as user_id, date_expired as user_date_expired 
FROM user 
WHERE id IN (13, 15)
) AS user
JOIN
(
SELECT COUNT(id) as item_count FROM item WHERE date_added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL     300 DAY) AND date_expired > CURDATE() 
) AS item
```

currently returns:

`user_id`   `user_date_expired` `item_count`

`13`    `2013-10-05 20:23:31`   `24`

`15`    `2013-08-08 22:21:09`   `24`

Appreciate any help.

Jonny

Comment: You need to post more information about the structure of each table. How does records in the `ITEM` table relate to records in the `USER` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from the information that you have provided that the license table is not required.

Here is the query rewritten with the correct join structure between the user and item tables.

```
SELECT  U.ID            AS user_id
        ,U.date_expired AS user_date_expired 
        ,COUNT(I.id)    AS item_count 
FROM    USER U
INNER JOIN
        ITEM I
ON      I.user_id = U.id
WHERE   U.id IN (13,15)
AND     I.date_added > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL  300 DAY) 
AND     I.date_expired > CURDATE()     
GROUP BY
        U.ID
        ,U.date_expired
```

Comment: Just going through it, it only returns the count for ID #13 nothing for Id #15

Comment: What result does the following give you? `SELECT COUNT(I.id) FROM ITEM I WHERE I.user_id = 15` - My guess is that user 15 has no items. If you need users without items included change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: It returns 7. Which is right, they both have records in there.

Comment: I just put a `GROUP BY u.id` at the end of the statement and it now returns 2 rows with the id, expiry and item count. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Skip the subqueries and use plain join for all three tables, and then add a `group by` clause for all columns that should be equal on each result row.